# Receiving message from blocked user xmpp

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xmpp, xmppframework

I blocked a user in xmpp
at still receiving message form this user

I'm using this code for block user

```
[xmppPrivacy retrieveListWithName:@"Block_List"];
[xmppPrivacy setActiveListName:@"Block_List"];
NSString *strJid= @"551924b3cfc4a3a80800000e";
strJid=[strJid stringByAppendingFormat:@"@62.10.47.43"];
NSXMLElement *privacyElement = [XMPPPrivacy privacyItemWithType:@"jid" value:strJid action:@"deny" order:1];
[XMPPPrivacy blockIQs:privacyElement];
[XMPPPrivacy blockMessages:privacyElement];
[XMPPPrivacy blockPresenceIn:privacyElement];
[XMPPPrivacy blockPresenceOut:privacyElement];
NSLog(@"-------> PRIVACY ELEMENT: %@", privacyElement);
NSArray *arrayPrivacy = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:privacyElement, nil];
[xmppPrivacy setListWithName:@"Block_List" items:arrayPrivacy];
```

i also get privacy list form openfire

```
<item type="jid" value="551924b3cfc4a3a80800000e@62.10.47.43" action="deny" order="1"><iq/><message/><presence-in/><presence-out/></item>
```

it shows that `551924b3cfc4a3a80800000e@62.10.47.43` blocked but still receiving message form this user

but when i run this code first time message are not receiving but after app restart message receiving

Comment: we have found same issue as we are able to block and unblock user but as soon as we kill the app or reinstall it is not working...any idea or suggestion @suthar

Comment: @DhavalBhadania have you found solution ?

Comment: Not yet 
I have used one workaround which is just save blocked user in userdefault and ignore the message if user is blocked